# Data Filter in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I have a question related to data filter.

Can we check the filtered record into marketing cloud?

I created an automation with below activities -

1. Query activity: This activity will update my sync DE to standard DE.
2. Data Filter: This will take only those record which has a birthday today.
3. Email

So I want to see the data coming after the filter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating and running a data filter will create a new data extension with the filtered results in it - you set the name of this Data Extension when you are setting up the filter (see image below). After it has run, you should see a new data extension with your results in it.

[image]